# Modify what Text Field is displaying

Tags: reactjs, field, admin-on-rest, react-admin

I have my `<ReferenceField>` where I get some data to work with. In this case, I get attribute `odata.type` from my API. I want my `<TextField>` to display this attribute but I want to slightly modify the output that is displayed. Right now the attribute is displayed like this: `HardwareDatabase.CPU`. Basically I need to modify this output to be liek this: `CPU`.

Here is my code I described earlier:

```
  <ReferenceField label="Type" source="id" reference="Hardware">
    <TextField source="odata.type"/>
  </ReferenceField>
```

Any ideas how can I modify the output of the field?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the value of your `odata.type` always in that format? like this `<somestring>.<valuestring>`? and you always want to get the `valuestring`?

Comment: @JkAlombro Yes, it is exactly like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ReferenceField label="Type" source="id" reference="Hardware">
   <FunctionField label="Name" render={record => record ? record["odata.type"].split(".")[1] : null} />
 </ReferenceField>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `FunctionField`:

```
<ReferenceField label="Type" source="id" reference="Hardware">
    <FunctionField label="Name" render={record => record ? record.odata.type.split(".")[1] : null} />
</ReferenceField>
```

Documentation: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#functionfield

**NOTE**: Be aware that the record may be undefined if the fetch call made by react-admin hasn't been resolved yet. This happens because react-admin renders the UI immediatly with the data it may have in its redux store already (optimistic rendering). You'll have to check that `record` isn't `undefined` before accessing it

Comment: This solution throws this error: 
Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
I guess the problem is in the name of the attribute itself, do you have any idea how to deal with this?

Comment: Console.log the record and check the path is ok

Comment: It seems like record is undefined for me, or at least thats what console returns to me.

Comment: Also, I have just tried to put there record.Name, which is returned just fine. The issu must be in the attribute itself. I guess the name is not really appropriate. I dont really know how to workaround this.

Comment: The record may be undefined until the fetch returns. Check if it is undefined and return null or the data you expect when it isn't